# Cognitive face detection is not working when I try to upload the image with a face mask

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, face-detection, azure-cognitive-services, face-recognition

Any suggestions on how to get info of the image with a mask in cognitive face recognition?
    When I upload image with headwear or eyeglasses then cognitive service returns the image information but when picking an image with mask, Cognitive service doesn't return any information. That means my implementation of cognitive service is not able to recognize the image with the mask. If anybody has faced this issue and resolved it please suggest me a solution.

```
  public string subscriptionKey = "88c**************************f7";

  public string uriBase = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect";

//Method to pick an image from the gallery
 async void btnPick_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
                {

                    return;
                }

                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
                {
                    PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium
                });
                if (file == null) return;
                imgSelected.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => {
                    var stream = file.GetStream();
                    return stream;
                });
                MakeAnalysisRequest(file.Path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string test = ex.Message;
            }

        }

> //convert Convert image to byte array

 public byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(string imageFilePath)
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream =
                new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
                return binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
            }
        }

> //Method to get image information from the detection Url

 public async void MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            string requestParameters = "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false" +
                "&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses," +
                "emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise";

            string uri = uriBase + "?" + requestParameters;
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);

            using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //***************************************************
            //Here it return null in case of mask else its working fine 
        //***************************************************

                List<ResponseModel> faceDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseModel>>(contentString);

                if (faceDetails.Count != 0)
                {
                    lblTotalFace.Text = "Total Faces : " + faceDetails.Count;
                    lblGender.Text = "Gender : " + faceDetails[0].faceAttributes.gender;
                    lblAge.Text = "Total Age : " + faceDetails[0].faceAttributes.age;

                    Console.WriteLine(faceDetails[0].faceAttributes.accessories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.type == "mask").confidence);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There a 2 different things that you must have in mind:

- Some faces might not be seen by the services, see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/concepts/face-detection?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#input-data):

> Some faces might not be detected because of technical challenges.
> Extreme face angles (head pose) or face occlusion (objects such as
> sunglasses or hands that block part of the face) can affect detection.
> Frontal and near-frontal faces give the best results.

- There are currently 2 detection models in Face API: "detection_01" and "detection_02". This latest model (existing since May 2019 if I remember well) has better performances (especially for rotated or partially hidden faces) but is not providing all the information in output that model 1 is giving.

### Difference in detection models

I made a quick demo using a the "Cognitive Workbench" demo portal (available [here](https://cognitive-workbench.azurewebsites.net/vision/face)) with the following image:
[image: Sample]

With detection_01: no face found

With detection_02: the face is found, as you can see in this capture:

[image: result with detection02]

But if you need to use specific attributes from the face, this might not solve your problem. See API documentation extract:

[image: API Detection models info]